# Affect an element with no relation to initially selected element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<input id="checkboxWithGeneralSiblingSelector" type="checkbox"/>
<span id="span1">Text</span>
<br/><br/>
<input id="checkboxWithoutGeneralSiblingSelector" type="checkbox"/>
<span id="span2">Text2</span>
```

And CSS:

```
#checkboxWithGeneralSiblingSelector:checked ~ #span1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#checkboxWithoutGeneralSiblingSelector:checked #span2 {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

The first one works fine, it looks at its general siblings and gets the element with ID `span`, so I assumed the second one would look at the entire DOM and give me the element with id `span2`. But then I realized that no operator is actually the "descendants" operator aka it looks for a `span2` element inside the initially selected one.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zewejvcf/1/)

*This fiddle is oversimplified, in my case the span is in no relation with the checkbox, aka it cannot be selected with either `+`, `>` or `~`*

EDIT: Simplified example of my DOM:

```
<span id="toBeAffected">
...
<div>
    <div>
        <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I affect an item with no specific DOM relation to the current one, when the effect needs to be conditioned by a state of the initially selected item?**

Comment: Does this have to be achieved via CSS only, or can/would you use a JS solution also?

Comment: @dippas Added example of my DOM.

Comment: @Aember I can, definitely. But I really feel like this should be doable via CSS

Comment: @iuliu.net you can't affect parent in CSS, because there  is no parent selector in CSS

Comment: You cannot affect any element that preceeds the trigger element in the DOM. Affecting subsequent elements is possible depend on the structure. This is why Javascript exists

Comment: So basically, the only things you can select are the ones on the same level or lower than the selected element?

Comment: Essentially...yes.

Comment: Oh.. ok. This feels like a really needed feature to me tho. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not a question of whether you can affect an element with no structural relation to the current one, but whether you can express this relation in a selector. In theory, with :has(), a structural relationship can be expressed between *any two elements* using a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for :has pseudoclass, and then do something like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zewejvcf/3/)   (Today, April 2016, it doesn't work in any browser)

```
.sibiling:has(input:checked)  ~  #toBeAffected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is an helpful link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/2594354

Comment: Does this work for you? It doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Oh, I was misreading. "wait for :has pseudoclass". Alright xD